# Convert databricks noteboooks.dbc into standard .py files

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

I often get sent databricks notebooks from various sources to move around / look at / refactor. Due to different tenancies I can't log into the actual environment. These are usually sent as `.dbc` files and I can convert them by opening up a new databricks enviroment are re-saving them as a .py file. I was wondering if there was a method where I could do this from command line, like `nb-convert` for Juypter ?

it's a little bit of a pain to import a whole host of files, then re-convert to python just for the sake of reading code.

Source control is not always an option due to permissions.

Comment: I don't know a method like that but maybe using the [Workspace CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/workspace-cli.html) might help a bit to export/import multiple notebooks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the .dbc in your Databricks workspace, for example in the Shared directory.
Then, as suggested by Carlos, install the Databricks CLI on your local computer and [set it up](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/index.html#set-up-the-cli).

```
pip install databricks-cli
databricks configure --token
```

and run the following to import the .py notebooks into your local folder

```
mkdir export_notebooks
cd export_notebooks
databricks workspace export_dir /Shared ./
```

Comment: If you don't/can't have access to a token, you can also configure the token without the token by simply running ```databricks configure```. It will prompt you with the user and password. Don't know if it is better in your case but hopefully it can help.

Answer (score 0):

I also publish a tool to unpack dbc archive files into their corresponding python and markdown files at https://github.com/activescott/dbcexplode

It doesn't require you to have a databricks workspace or account you can run it all locally.